# Use variable in Graph Title

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing

I wanna include count of threads in the Graph Title like this :
[image]

Now, this is just text `${__threadNum}`, but I want to set value depend the current  `Number of Threads`. Is that possible ?